# mysql insert 2 subsets from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, join, insert, subset, sql-insert

I have a table with attributes to a product:

```
product_attributes
+------------+--------------+-------------+------+
| product_id | attribute_id | language_id | text |
+------------+--------------+-------------+------+
| 1          | 2            | 2           | bla  |
| 1          | 2            | 3           | blo  |
| 1          | 3            | 2           | foo  |
| 1          | 4            | 3           | bar  |
+------------+--------------+-------------+------+
```

and I have another table called `product` with multiple product_ids that do not exist in the `product_attributes` table.
I would like to copy all data from `product_attributes` where `product_id` = 1 and insert them for ALL the ids in the `product` table.

This is what I had so far but it does not work.

```
INSERT INTO `product_attribute`(`product_id`, `attribute_id`, `language_id`, `text`) SELECT (SELECT 'product_id' FROM `product`), `attribute_id`, `language_id`, `text` FROM `product_attribute` WHERE `product_id` = '1';
```

It says the subquery returns more than 1 row (which it does, that's the point), I just don't know how to solve this with 2 subsets.

Comment: `INSERT INTO product_attribute(product_id, attribute_id, language_id, \`text\`) SELECT product_id, attribute_id, language_id, \`text\` FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id = 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cross join :

[1] solution :

```
INSERT INTO `product_attributes`(`product_id`, `attribute_id`,`language_id`, `text`) 
select product_id,v.attribute_id,v.language_id,v.text 
from product
cross join (SELECT  attribute_id, language_id, text 
            FROM product_attributes            
            WHERE product_id = '1') v ;
```

[2] solution :

```
INSERT INTO `product_attributes`(`product_id`, `attribute_id`,`language_id`, `text`) 
select b.product_id,`attribute_id`, `language_id`, `text`
from product_attributes a 
CROSS join  product b
```

use above sql query it is perfect and it has no error.

your sql :

```
INSERT INTO `product_attribute`(`product_id`, `attribute_id`, `language_id`, `text`)
```

SELECT (SELECT 'product_id' FROM `product`), `attribute_id`, `language_id`, `text` 
  FROM `product_attribute` 
  WHERE `product_id` = '1';

**Here,in your sql (SELECT 'product_id' FROM `product`) returns 
more than  one value it is not possible in co-related sql.**

**when inner query behaves as a field then at a time it has only one value .**

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT 'product_id' FROM `product`)
```

In this query should be return more than one row.
I think this query should be not required.